# Wrap text of Table cell in exported Excel in BIRT

Tags: excel, birt

I am using BIRT 4.4.1 in eclipse for report generation.

I would like to wrap my text of Table Header, it works fine in webviewer but when i exported to excel the table cell text is in a single line, and also the text is overflowed. I dont want to make the cell width equal to the content, I would like to wrap the text based on its container width.

I have set the cell width and label whitespace property as auto. is it correct, or what do i do to make it work in exported excel report?

In Webview

[image]

After exported, Excel view

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In 4.4.2 export as XLS (not xlsx). As a workaround you can also add a line return within the text and that will appear correctly when you export to xlsx.

A third option that works with xlsx output is to select the text box in the cell, and in General Properties set the Whitespace to Preformatted. Then, either set the header cell size to a height that covers the required text OR in general properties of the entire report, set the layout to Auto Layout.

Comment: I've tried your third option that suites for me, but its not working.

Comment: Can you upload a sample report file? I tried it just now and it was working in a table.

Comment: I have solved by setting whitespace to 'preformatted' for the labels. Its working in excel but not in webviewer. so i would like it to be same in both webviewer and excel. so is  there any way to set this property only when i exported to excel?

Comment: Yes, you can set the default properties as you like and then you can select a cell or row and set its properties depending on the rendered output. For example, to change the properties of a table cell only during xlsx output, select the cell, and add an onRender script such as:

    if (reportContext.getOutputFormat() == "xlsx"){
       this.getStyle().whiteSpace = "pre";
       this.getStyle().backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }

Comment: Thanks, this is the top solution in my opinion!