# BIRT xlsx export doesn't wrap cell contents

Tags: export, birt, xlsx

I'm working with BIRT reports (version 4.6.x) within Eclipse and I'm trying to export whole report into .xlsx. Rerport contains header with some data, image and table with results.

When I try SPUDSOFT xls or xlsx, I still encounter the same error.
Data in the table are correctly wrapped (if the column is too narrow, height of the line is increased and so on), however the table header (with column lablels) remains single line and you can't correctly read its contents.

I use whitespace wrapping Normal and I've tried to use dynamic text instead of standard label with wrap function (as it's used in datasets).
But the header row is still with no wrapping. It looks good on the web, but doesn't work in excel.

Have you encountered the same problem? How do I wrap the header line?

See attached report - it's only a draft, but how do I set the lines to wrap their content? Try exporting it to xlsx.
[Test rptdesign sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/no2stasybq8uv0v/test.rptdesign?dl=1)

Comment: Have you defined a fixed width on the table header ? row or cell ?
p.s.
Your report sample is no longer available, so I just tried to guess.

Comment: Yes, fixed width would probably work - along with preformatted whitespace.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815963/wrap-text-of-table-cell-in-exported-excel-in-birt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrap text of Table cell in exported Excel in BIRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815963/wrap-text-of-table-cell-in-exported-excel-in-birt)